# How do I populate a set of Entity Framework Code first POCOS from SQL server (once off)?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-generation

We have custom code that wipes and initializes our test database by creating a few objects and saving them to  the DatabaseContext (we use Migrations for the schema, but not for the data). However, our tester has created a lot more data, and doesn't want to lose her test data when we do a clean deploy. I therefore have to figure out how to get the data from SQL Server into C# (once off), so it an be run with our data-initialization program.

My initial approach was to manually copy-paste the data into C# object initializers, but this got old quickly, since there are 100+ rows to copy.

My second approach was to create the objects using a SELECT statement in SQL Server, mixing the C# initializer syntax into the SQL SELECT statement, and then copying the C# strings generated by SQL Server back into Visual Studio.

Although the second approach seems OK, I was wondering if there's an obvious solution (apart from simply running a SQL INSERT script every time) that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with the approach mentioned in the question. Generating C# object initialializers in SQL Select Statements.

A few things I picked up, mostly obvious:

- CAST AS VARCHAR for all numeric fields (although SQL Server will give error if you don't).
- Dates: convert to VARCHAR and surround with DateTime.Parse()
- Use a CASE statement to convert SQL bool value (1/0) to true/false as strings.
- Enums: generate a cast.
- If using autonumber ids, remember to prefix instance names with a letter(s). Add the object to DataContext after initializing it.

Don't be afraid to reference your C# code in the generated code.  It isn't going to run in SQL Server in any case.

Comment: Two months on, I have an additional observation:

There were various tweaks that were introduced to the data, and rows were excluded. Initially, I modified the generated code, but later found that changing the underlying SQL made it far easier to control (this is generally regarded as a Best Practice, but in this case, it was validated). I would agree with the general wisdom that one should be extremely wary of modifying generated code.

Answer (score 0):

I would just create an SQL script that recreates the data in your DB.
You can run this script through the commandline or through C#...

Comment: This is an option I considered, but it was pointed out to me that refactoring of entities wouldn't be seamless in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You do have another option. Take a backup of the test database, load that backup into a new database on the same server as the target database, and when the migration is finished (including clearing the database) issue cross-database `INSERT...SELECT` statements.

The benefit of this approach is if the testing team gets another version they like, you can take a backup and overwrite the staging database with that allowing them to continually build more data.